# Python-mip and VSCode

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, optimization, import

I am using Python with VSCode (Ubuntu). I installed Python-mip, and it is running within the terminal. However, VSCode is not finding the library mip (from Python-mip).
For example, I am calling: `from mip import Model, xsum, maximize, BINARY` to import some required classes and definitions from Python-MIP and the VSCode is returning:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mip'`. How could I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pay attention to two points:

1. Select the interpreter with `mip` installed (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`)

   [image]

   *The interpreter version you choose will be displayed in the lower right corner of the vscode interface.*
2. Execute script using `Run Python File`

   [image]